# different conditions on different groups

Tags: sql, teradata

I have a table like this. I would like to get the first row grouped by id where acc1 is not null and if all the rows in the acc1 are null then i would want to get all the rows.

```
id  acc1    acc2
1   null    1
1   1   1
1   1   2
1   2   2
2   null    1
2   null    2
2   null    3
2   null    4
```

I would like to get an output like this:

```
id  acc1    acc2
1   1   1
2   null    1
2   null    2
2   null    3
2   null    4
```

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Comment: i tried using aggregate functions but still cant think of any good logic.

Comment: @Jacobm001: I'm not sure that's true.

Comment: yeah `union` is other way of doing this but cant we do this only using aggregate functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `acc1` is unique when not `null` (for each id):

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             rank() over (partition by id
                          order by (case when acc1 is null then 2 else 1 end), acct1
                         ) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

If it is not unique, this just requires a little more work:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id
                                order by acct1, acct2
                               ) as seqnum,
             count(acct1) over (partition by id) as cnt
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1 or cnt = 0;
```

This assumes that "first" is based on `acct1`, `acct2`.  SQL tables are inherently unordered, so you need a column that specifies the ordering.

Comment: i would want to retrieve first non null values for acc1 is the only condition required.

Comment: Teradata has a concept of `ROW_NUMBER`. You can simplify by using that (probably)...

Comment: Thanks as always for such a neat solution.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable
QUALIFY Max(acc1) Over (PARTITION BY id) IS NULL -- only NULLs
  OR Row_Number() Over (PARTITION BY id          -- or the first non-null value
                        ORDER BY acc1 NULLS LAST) = 1
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. will look into it and let you know.